# command from compose not executed in entrypoint.sh

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile for my python django project and then I have a docker-compose that I use to build and deploy my application. Currently, the compose file just have django app, nginx, and db server.

The **ENTRYPOINT** arg in my app's Dockerfile is the entrypoint.sh script which runs some migrations and at the end I have the `exec "$@"` line which should be executing the **Command** passed via the docker-compose.

But it seems that the command from the Dockerfile does not get executed or crashes.
I can see from the output of `docker ps -a --no-trunc` that the command is indeed being passed as an arg to the ENTRYPOINT.

I did try to move the command from the compose file to the entrypoint.sh, and the application starts just fine. But when it is being passed from the compose file, nothing happens.

I also tried to `echo "$@"` in order to check what was being received, but that's empty as well.

Here is my app's service in compose:

```
version: '3'
services:

  django_app:
    container_name: django_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: django_app:latest
    command: gunicorn app.wsgi:application --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 -t 300
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

This is the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py groups
python3 manage.py superuser_fromenv
python3 manage.py create_custom_permissions
echo "done"
echo "$@"
exec "$@"
```

Out of frustration I tried with `exec $@`, but didnt helped.

And, last but not the least, here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as BASE
FROM BASE as package

ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHONPATH="/opt/venv:$PYTHONPATH"
ENV APP_HOME="/home/app"
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY --from=build /opt/venv /opt/venv
COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN chmod +x  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap a command in `sh -c`, that shell consumes all of the extra arguments that are given (including the `CMD`) and doesn't pass them on to the inner command.  If you're using the entrypoint-wrapper pattern (which I frequently recommend) then you must not have an `sh -c` wrapper, either manually or using the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
# ENTRYPOINT must be JSON-array format and must not have `sh -c`
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

# CMD can be any valid Dockerfile command
CMD gunicorn app.wsgi:application --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 -t 300
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. But what i dont understand is that even if the command args are passed onto that shell, shouldnt it execute them? Like in this case, after executing the entrypoint.sh it would execute the command from the compose?

Comment: Try it without Docker: run `/bin/echo foo bar baz`, vs. `sh -c '/bin/echo foo' bar baz`.  The extra options are taken as positional parameters (starting with `$0`) to the `sh -c` command.